# Parameterless Constructor error in my controller at run time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, controller

**I am getting the parameterless constructor error.My code was running fine earlier when I was passing only Service layer instance into the constructor like this--**

```
   public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
     private readonly IProjectService _projectService; 
     public ProjectController(IProjectService projectService)
    {
        this._projectService = projectService;
    }
```

Then all my action methods below them.
**Problem arises when i thought of using some other interfaces in my controller so i tried something like this---**

```
  public class ProjectController : Controller
   {
    private readonly IProjectService _projectService;
    private readonly ICityService _cityService;
    private readonly ILocalityService _localityService;
    public ProjectController(IProjectService projectService)
    {
        this._projectService = projectService;
    }
    public ProjectController(ICityService cityService)
    {
        this._cityService = cityService;
    }
    public ProjectController(ILocalityService localityService)
    {
        this._localityService = localityService;
    }
```

**In this way, I was able to use the methods defined in other interfaces too.At compile time, i thought everything would work fine but now i am getting this error. I want to know is my approach wrong? what should i do so that i could use given interfaces and their methods from service layer.I have pasted my full code at http://pastebin.com/fspycG5p**

Comment: Which IOC (Dependecy Injection) you are using. Seems it is not resolving the Dependencies?

Comment: Please paste the code where you are resolving dependencies

Comment: @Chander.k Ohh thanks for recognizing the root cause first let me try...btw i am using unity container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a single constructor that takes in all the interfaces, rather than several constructors with a single interface.

```
 public class ProjectController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IProjectService _projectService;
    private readonly ICityService _cityService;
    private readonly ILocalityService _localityService;

    public ProjectController(IProjectService projectService, 
                             ICityService cityService, 
                             ILocalityService localityservice)
    {
        this._projectService = projectService;
        this._cityService = cityService;
        this._localityService = localityService;
    }
}
```

This is assuming that you have configured the rest of you IOC correctly.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava No problem. Thanks. :)